# Calling functions within Workflows in Powershell 4.0

Tags: powershell, workflow, powershell-4.0

I have a set of functions which need to be called from within and without a workflow in a Powershell Script which uses a workflow to manage remote computers. I have tried defining a module to pass to the InlineScript but using the method below the inline script cannot find the Dynamic Module "SharedFunctions"

```
#Script Only Functions
function funct1 {}
function funct2 {}

#Script and Workflow Functions
New-Module SharedFunctions {
    function sharedFunct1 {}
    function sharedFunct2 {}
} -Name SharedFunctions | Import-Module

#Workflow
workflow w1 {
    Param( [string[]] $computerList)

    foreach -parallel( $computer in $computerList ){
        #Shared Function out of Inline Script
        sharedFunct1


        InlineScript{
            #Shared Function inside InlineScript
            sharedFunct2
            #Do stuff
        } -PSRequiredModules "SharedFunctions"
    }
}

<# Local Script #>
funct1    
sharedFunct1
w1
```

I get the error message

```
The specified module 'SharedFunctions' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (FunctionModule:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
    + PSComputerName        : [localhost]
```

I read that modules can be imported within Workflows. Is this not possible with Dynamic Modules? How can I call shared functions from within the workflow? `sharedFunct1` could be a task such as updating a log file on the host computer with updates from each thread operating on remote computers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that importing modules can only be done from file and not from memory. This seems to have done the trick -
File 1 -

```
<# MAIN.PS1 #>
function funct1 {}
function funct2 {}

#Workflow
workflow w1 {

    Param( [string[]] $computerList)

    $modDir = "Some Directory"
    Import-Module $$modDir

    foreach -parallel( $computer in $computerList ){
        #Shared Function out of Inline Script
        sharedFunct1


        InlineScript{
            #Import module in each Inline Script
            Import-Module $using:$modDir

            #Shared Function inside InlineScript
            sharedFunct2
            #Do stuff
        }
    }
}

<# Local Script #>
funct1    
sharedFunct1
w1
```

File 2 -

```
<# MODULE.PSM1 #>    
#Script and Workflow Functions        
function sharedFunct1 {}
function sharedFunct2 {}
```

However I would prefere to stick to just one file so if anybody knows how to import Dynamic Modules into workflows I would love to see it.